# How does numpy's argpartition work on the documentation's example?

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to understand numpy's argpartition function.  I have made the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html)'s example as basic as possible.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([3, 4, 2, 1])
print("x: ", x)

a=np.argpartition(x, 3)
print("a: ", a)

print("x[a]:", x[a])
```

This is the output...

```
('x: ', array([3, 4, 2, 1]))
('a: ', array([2, 3, 0, 1]))
('x[a]:', array([2, 1, 3, 4]))
```

In the line a=np.argpartition(x, 3) isn't the kth element the last element (the number 1)?  If it is number 1, when x is sorted shouldn't 1 become the first element (element 0)?

In x[a], why is 2 the first element "in front" of 1?

What fundamental thing am I missing?

Comment: `partition/argpartition` split at the kth element _by order_, not by position. The latter would not require a dedicated algorithm, because you could simply do something like `np.concatenate([x[x<x[3]], x[x ==x[3]], x[[x>x[3]])`. The smart bit about `partition` is  finding the kth element without doing a full sort.

Comment: @PaulPanzer: The advantage of a naive `partition` compared to `concatenate` would be that it could it in one single pass.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

The more complete answer to what [argpartition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argpartition.html) does is in the documentation of [partition](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.partition.html), and that one says:

> Creates a copy of the array with its elements rearranged in such a way
>   that the value of the element in k-th position is in the position it
>   would be in a sorted array. All elements smaller than the k-th element
>   are moved before this element and all equal or greater are moved
>   behind it. The ordering of the elements in the two partitions is
>   undefined.

So, for the input array `3, 4, 2, 1`, the sorted array would be `1, 2, 3, 4`.

The result of `np.partition([3, 4, 2, 1], 3)` will have the correct value (i.e. same as sorted array) in the 3rd (i.e. last) element. The correct value for the 3rd element is `4`.

Let me show this for all values of `k` to make it clear:

- `np.partition([3, 4, 2, 1], 0)` - [**1**, 4, 2, 3]
- `np.partition([3, 4, 2, 1], 1)` - [1, **2**, 4, 3]
- `np.partition([3, 4, 2, 1], 2)` - [1, 2, **3**, 4]
- `np.partition([3, 4, 2, 1], 3)` - [2, 1, 3, **4**]

*In other words:* the k-th element of the result is the same as the k-th element of the sorted array. All elements before k are smaller than or equal to that element. All elements after it are greater than or equal to it.

The same happens with `argpartition`, except `argpartition` returns indices which can then be used for form the same result.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. May I ask what could be a potential use case for this method?

Comment: I assume that potential use case could be to get `top_num_of_scores` from some array filled with unsorted scores `ids_of_top_n_unsorted = np.argpartition(array_of_unsorted_scores, -num_top)[-num_top:]`

Comment: I saw it used as selected top n largest coefficients in features selections.

Answer (score 11):

Similar to @Imtinan, I struggled with this. I found it useful to break up the function into the arg and the partition.

Take the following array:

```
array = np.array([9, 2, 7, 4, 6, 3, 8, 1, 5])

the corresponding indices are: [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8] where 8th index = 5 and 0th = 9
```

if we do `np.partition(array, k=5)`, the code is going to take the 5th element (not index) and then place it into a new array. It is then going to put those elements < 5th element before it and that > 5th element after, like this:

`pseudo output: [lower value elements, 5th element, higher value elements]`

if we compute this we get:

`array([3, 5, 1, 4, 2, 6, 8, 7, 9])`

This makes sense as the 5th element in the original array = 6, [1,2,3,4,5] are all lower than 6 and [7,8,9] are higher than 6. Note that the elements are not ordered.

The arg part of the `np.argpartition()` then goes one step further and swaps the elements out for their respective indices in the original array. So if we did:

`np.argpartition(array, 5)` we will get:

`array([5, 8, 7, 3, 1, 4, 6, 2, 0])`

from above, the original array had this structure [index=value]
[0=9, 1=2, 2=7, 3=4, 4=6, 5=3, 6=8, 7=1, 8=5]

you can map the value of the index to the output and you with satisfy the condition:

`argpartition() = partition()`, like this:

[index form] array([5, 8, 7, 3, 1, 4, 6, 2, 0]) becomes

```
[3, 5, 1, 4, 2, 6, 8, 7, 9]
```

which is the same as the output of `np.partition(array)`,

```
array([3, 5, 1, 4, 2, 6, 8, 7, 9])
```

Hopefully, this makes sense, it was the only way I could get my head around the arg part of the function.

Answer (score 7):

i remember having a hard time figuring it out too, maybe the documentation is written badly but this is what it means

When you do `a=np.argpartition(x, 3)` then x is sorted in such a way that only the element at the k'th index will be sorted (in our case k=3)

So when you run this code basically you are asking what would the value of the 3rd index be in a sorted array. Hence the output is `('x[a]:', array([2, 1, 3, 4]))`where only element 3 is sorted.

As the document suggests all numbers smaller than the kth element are before it (in no particular order) hence you get 2 before 1, since its no particular order.

i hope this clarifies it, if you are still confused then feel free to comment :)

Comment: Thank you.  The parts that say "x is sorted in such a way that only the element in the position 3 will be sorted" really helped.  Thank you. PS. I ended up ticking the above as the correct answer because it had the nice code example and we can only pick one answer.